# Laravel4: Call to a member function update() on a non-object

Tags: php, laravel

Following are my codes:

**Model:**

```
class Slide extends \Eloquent {

    // Add your validation rules here
    public static $rules = [
        'title' => 'required|between:3,100',
        'image' => 'required',
        'url' => 'url',
        'active' => 'integer'
    ];

    // Don't forget to fill this array
    protected $fillable = ['title', 'image', 'url', 'active'];

}
```

**Controller Update Method:**

```
public function update($id)
{
    $slide = Slide::find($id);

    $validator = Validator::make($data = Input::all(), Slide::$rules);

    if ($validator->fails())
    {
        return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
    }

    $slide->update($data);

    return Redirect::route('admin.slides.index')
            ->with('message', 'Slide has been updated.')
            ->with('message-type', 'alert-success');
}
```

**Route:**

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'admin'), function() {
    # Slides Management
    Route::resource('slides', 'AdminSlidesController', array('except' => array('show')));
});
```

**Form in View:**

```
{{ Form::model($slide, array('route' => 'admin.slides.update', $slide->id, 'method' => 'put')) }}
    @include('admin/slides/partials/form')
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Partial Form is simple form, not sure if I need to share it here or not. Let me know.

**Error:**

Edit page loads perfectly and populates data from db, but when I submit the edit form, I get following error:

> Call to a member function update() on a non-object

The following line seems to be creating problems:

> $slide->update($data);

I have searched over the internet for solution but nothing is working. Have tried composer dump_autoload, even tried doing everything from scratch in a new project, still same issue. :(

Help please!!

---- Edit ----

Just quickly tried following:

```
public function update($id)
{
    $slide = Slide::find($id);
    $slide->title = Input::get('title');
    $slide->save();

    return Redirect::route('admin.slides.index')
            ->with('message', 'Slide has been updated.')
            ->with('message-type', 'alert-success');
}
```

**Now the error:**

> Creating default object from empty value

### **----- Solution: -----**

The problem was with my form as suggested by @lukasgeiter 
I changed my form to following at it worked like a charm:

```
{{ Form::model($slide, array('route' => array('admin.slides.update', $slide->id), 'method' => 'put')) }}
```

Comment: This means `$slide` is NULL. Try doing `dd($slide)` to see if anything got returned. And also follow @K.Toress answer on `save()` function.

Comment: You are scoping the `$data` variable inside the function, could that be a problem ? Is the `$data` variable accessible outside of its scope ? In other words, is `$data` accessible by `save/update` method ?

Comment: Tried @K.Toress's answer, edited my original post with the error I've got.

Comment: check whether there is a `Slide` for the `$id` as @TimLewis said ?

Comment: About the scope of $data, not sure about this.

Comment: dd($slide); give null and dd($slide->id); gives an error " Trying to get property of non-object "

Comment: thats because there is no slide for given `$id`, please check with a existing  record.

Comment: `non-object` means you don't have an object, meaning `Slide::find` or `Slide::get` isn't returning anything based on the parameters passed to it. Always check your object is what you think it is before running any changes on it. Last thing you want is to save something you didn't intend.

Comment: I checked it extensively, the slide for that $id exists. Infact I am sending update request from edit page of the same slide i.e. slides/2/edit. However, check @lukasgeiter's response that worked. The problem was with my form route instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual problem is not your controller but your form.
It should be this instead:

```
{{ Form::model($slide, array('route' => array('admin.slides.update', $slide->id), 'method' => 'put')) }}
```

This mistake causes the controller to receive no id. Then `find()` yields no result and returns `null`.

I recommend besides fixing the form you also use `findOrFail()` which will throw a `ModelNotFoundException` if no record is found.

```
$slide = Slide::findOrFail($id);
```

Comment: You're the man. The problem was indeed with my form. Added that array to my route name like you've suggested and it worked like a charm. I was using findOrFail($id) initially and it was giving me ModelNotFoundException, changed it to find($id) which fixed the model not found exception but gave the error I mentioned in my original post.

Comment: Since I wasn't sending route name and slide id in an array, the update method in controller wasn't receiving the slide id, hence it wasn't able to fetch anything from database.

Answer (score 5):

use `$slide->save();` instead of `$slide->update($data);`

to update a model please read the [laravel doc here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent)

> To update a model, you may retrieve it, change an attribute, and use the save method:

EX :

```
$user = User::find(1);

$user->email = 'john@foo.com';

$user->save();
```

Comment: Tried that, now it says:  **Call to a member function save() on a non-object **

Comment: I'm using resource controller, the example you've given isn't working. I've already tired that.

Comment: please do as the example. get the `Slide` and assign the field data based on inputs and save it.

Comment: Edited my first post and added the error I'm getting after trying this.